# How to know which template I am currently working in magento 2

Tags: magento2, template

good morning everyone, I am a little bit new on Magento 2.x, I am working the full time make some changes in some view which contains a template but I suffer and struggle to know which template in question I am working within the current path, can anyone please give me some hints how to know which template I am working within the current path

--> can anyone save my time by telling me how, please?

Comment: Go to admin panel > Choose Store > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront > Click Yes to Enabled Template Path Hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Check your store mode

> deploy:mode:show

**First enable Developer mode**

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

**Enable Template Path Hints in Admin Configuration**

> **Step 1**: Go to admin panel
>
> **Step 2**: Choose Store > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront
>
> **Step 3**: Click Yes to Enabled Template Path Hints

**And you can also enble and disable using command**

> php bin/magento dev:template-hints:enable
>
> php bin/magento dev:template-hints:disable

**Enabled Template Path Hints for Admin**

> Store > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Enabled Template Path Hints for Admin > Yes

***Note:if not working then run magento setup upgrade and flush magento cache command***
***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: i follow this steps bro , but it's still telling me in debug option that this is not provided in production mode, but and my mode is developer !!??

Comment: So please check you mode and if developer then again follow above steps and run setup upgrade and clean and flush magento cache. Then it's works

Comment: i am in developer mode bro , but i can't access to this 'Debug > Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront', the field is disable and gives me this message bellow => "Not available in production mode."

Comment: So bro it's means your store in production mode please set into developer mode .

Comment: Used this comman  deploy:mode:show to show your current mode.

Comment: Please set production to Developer mode and then follow above steps.

Comment: this is what his commande tell me : "bin/magento deploy:mode:show" ===> "Current application mode: developer. (Note: Environment variables may override this value.)"

Comment: Now follow above Steps to enable Temple hint.

Comment: Let me inform it's works or not

Comment: one more time :( , it tells me in debug option " 
Not available in production mode."

Comment: I think you are run command on different place please check and make you sure command run at proper magento root .

Comment: Your store stiill on production not set developer . Without set Developer mode you can't set yes to show template path.

Comment: but i run the command in the web directory

Comment: If command run then it set Developer mode not in your case not so you doing something wrong.

Comment: Please check it's small mistake find it.

Comment: the value of the  mode is it stores in DB or in a simple file

Comment: please update me can you see Template hint ?

Comment: Sure bro i will update you

Comment: Above solut is works for you

Comment: yeah i mark it as solution , can i have you contact if i face any futur error in magento 2

Comment: can you give e your skype bro please if i face some error for my future learning?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable template path hint to show which template is rendering on  specific page.
for this follow below step.

Make sure you are in developer mode to show this option.

```
Step 1: Go to admin panel
Step 2: Choose Store > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront
Step 3: Click Yes to Enabled Template Path Hints
```

**Enable Template Path Hints via Command Line:**

```
php bin/magento dev:template-hints:enable
```

For disable it

```
bin/magento dev:template-hints:disable
```

then

```
bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: i follow all this step , but it's still telling me in debug option that  this is not provided in production mode, but and my mode is developer !!??

Answer (score 0):

Whilst enabling template hints is a good option I prefer to just search for something that appears remotely unique, for example if I'm looking for the template that renders the copyright text I just search all PHTML files (`*.phtml`) for `class="copyright"` and within a second my editor tells me the file is `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/copyright.phtml`.

I find that method much quicker and easier than enabling template hints, the downside is if there is not something unique to search for it may return several templates.

Comment: good bro n but when the page is xml file not phtml , some time it's hard to fin which class used for example in a field

Comment: For XML files it's a case of search `*.xml` files, for example if you want to find where `class="page-header"` comes from you can search for `htmlClass="page-header"`. If you're unsure what file type it is you can search both for `page-header`. If you're new to Magento then the template hints method will likely be better for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple:

1: Sign in to Magento admin panel

2: Then navigate to the: Store > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront

3: Click Yes to Enabled Template Path Hints

Ensure that you've enabled the developer mode. Here's the command to enable the developer mode: bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

I hope that will work for you if you need more help, follow this official guide by Magento: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/debug-theme.html